# Javascript - retrieve random image from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, random, processing

I'm trying to write a program using Javascript and the p5.js library to trigger a random image from an array whenever a peak in an audio file is detected. p5's sound library can detect the audio peak for me and then trigger a function upon that audio peak. However, I don't have much experience in Javascript so I'm not sure where to go from here. I've created an array of images and am planning on creating a function using math.Random to grab one of these images. Can I then call that function within my triggerBeat function?

Also, I've set the image as the background so that it's not within p5's draw function, so I'm trying to change the bg variable. I've preloaded the background image, and I've also got code within the preload function to allow the user to upload an audio file.

Sorry if this doesn't make a ton of sense. I'm pretty new to Javascript and I've spent most of today trying to wrap my head around it.

EDIT: updated code

```
 var cnv, song, fft, peakDetect, img, bg;
 var imageset = new Array("1.png","2.png","3.png");


function preload(){
  img = loadImage("1.png");
  var loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
  document.getElementById("audiofile").onchange = function(event) {
      if(event.target.files[0]) {
          if(typeof song != "undefined") {
              song.disconnect();
              song.stop();
          }


          song = loadSound(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
          loader.classList.add("loading");
      }
  }
}


function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(900,900);
  drawImage(imageset[0]);

  fft = new p5.FFT();
  peakDetect = new p5.PeakDetect();
  setupSound();
  peakDetect.onPeak(drawImage(imageset));

}


function draw() {
  drawImage();
}

function drawImage(arr) {
  var bg = loadImage(random(arr));
  background(bg);
  fill(0);
  text('play', width/2, height/2);

  fft.analyze();
  peakDetect.update(fft);
}


function setupSound() {
  cnv.mouseClicked( function() {
    if (song.isPlaying() ) {
      song.stop();
    } else {
      song.play();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Math.floor(Math.random() * yourArray.length)

Comment: You can surely optimize the way you store your images array.
You can try creating an array like : 
let imageArray = [ 'dog.png', 'dog2.png', 'dog3.png' ... ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

p5 has math functions, one of which is random.

> If one argument is given and it is an array, returns a random element from that array.

**EDIT**
As the result was more messy after answering the initial question, I updated the whole code.

```
var cnv, song, fft, peakDetect, img, bg;
var imageset = new Array("pic1.png","pic2.png","pic3.png", "pic4.png");
var imagesArr = [];

//next line will make p5 global. Otherwise would the p5 functions be
//accessable from p5 struct functions only.
new p5(); 

/*******************************************************************
* PRELOAD 
* we are using for loading images/audios only
********************************************************************/
function preload(){
    //load all images from 'imageset' into 'imagesArr'
    for(var i=0; i<imageset.length; i++){
        loadImage('../img/'+imageset[i], function(img) {
            imagesArr.push(img);
        });    
    }

    // next lets load soundfile(s).
    //song = loadSound("../snd/test.mp3");
    // I used testfile, didn't touch nor tested your code here,
    // BUT, again:
    // you should only (pre)load you sounds here, setting event should go
    // to the setup()


  var loader = document.querySelector(".loader");     
  document.getElementById("audiofile").onchange = function(event) {
      if(event.target.files[0]) {
          if(typeof song != "undefined") {
              song.disconnect();
              song.stop();
          }
          song = loadSound(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
          loader.classList.add("loading");
      }
  }
}

/*******************************************************************
* SETUP 
* run once, use for initialisation.
********************************************************************/
function setup() {
  //create canvas, draw initial background and text
  cnv = createCanvas(900,900);
  drawBackground();

  text('play', width/2, height/2);
  //initiate fft, peakdetect. Set event (onpeak)
  fft = new p5.FFT();
  peakDetect = new p5.PeakDetect();
  setupSound();
  peakDetect.onPeak(drawBackground);
}

/*******************************************************************
* DRAW
* endless loop. Here happens all the action.
* But you cannot draw your background here, as it is done by event. 
********************************************************************/
function draw(){
    //fft and peakdetecting are in use.
    fft.analyze();
    peakDetect.update(fft);
}

function drawBackground() {
    background(255);
    background(random(imagesArr));
}

function setupSound() {
  cnv.mouseClicked( function() {
    if (song.isPlaying() ) {
      song.stop();
    } else {
      song.play();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: This is super helpful, thank you! When I run the script, though, I get  ReferenceError: imageset is not defined, even though I defined it as an array?

Comment: Did you pass it in the setup function? like : setup(imageset); when you called that function?

Comment: Didn't noticed about used function name (draw()). P5 is looping draw() function automatically which caused it to run without parameters, hence the ref.error.

Comment: Hmm okay, I updated the code and it's no longer returning errors, but now I'm not receiving my image (or anything from the drawImage function). I updated the code in the OP. Still trying to figure out what might have gone wrong

Answer (score 0):

Have `yourArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * yourArray.length)]` to get a random img by calling it in your triggerBeat function